# Possibility of hierarchy with $UP$ class?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, oracles, polynomial-hierarchy

I am not sure if this is a cheap query. However I am unable to find this myself. So I am posting here. The standard complexity class is built with $NP$ and $coNP$ and leads up to $PSPACE$. The reference https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01184809.pdf gives some classes for which we have oracles with respect to which $UP$ is not low.

1. Which classes are known to be low with $UP$ oracle ($PSPACE$ is one of them)?
2. Is there a hierarchy to concoct with $UP$ and $coUP$ analogous to the standard polynomial hierarchy and in particular is there an analog of $PSPACE$?

Comment: I know that if ${\bf UP}$ is low for ${\bf \#P}$  then ${\bf UP} = {\bf CoUP}$.   You can read it here =  J. KOBLER, U. SCHONING, AND J. TORAN, On counting and approximation, Acta Inform. 26 (1989),
363-379.

Comment: @TayfunPay Very interesting. Then likely that there is an unambiguous version of things and a fewbiguous version of things.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 2. answered in references

a. https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9907033.pdf

b. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=19DD617ABDB31709CA0BEF797C283867?doi=10.1.1.60.9357&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: Your second reference has a [revision](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397597000054), which removes an incorrect proof of "Theorem" 5, among other things.